# Convert each row in pandas dataframe to a dataframe with one column containing in each row an array of values previously in seperate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
0 a b c d
1 b c d e
2 f o n e
3 o b l e
```

And I want to convert it into this:

```
0[a,b,c,d]
1[b,c,d,e]
2[f,o,n,e]
3[o,b,l,e]
```

Such that I go from x columns (4 in this case) to an array containing those values in a single column.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: `df.agg(list, axis=1)`?

Comment: surprisingly I couldn't find a duplicate, if anyone has a link

Answer (score 3):

To aggregate many columns into a Series of lists, use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) on `axis=1`:

```
s = df.agg(list, axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    [a, b, c, d]
1    [b, c, d, e]
2    [f, o, n, e]
3    [o, b, l, e]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.apply(list, 1).to_frame()`. Consider if you actually want that, though. Having lists in dataframes defeats the purpose of pandas - fast vectorized operations on tabular data.

edit: or just `df.to_numpy()` depending on what your plan is.